# character focus on asp.net tree view

Tags: asp.net

I have a treeview inside a panel. The tree view has a parent and a child. The focus needs to go to the corresponding parent or child when I press any character on the keyboard. I tried to Google a solution but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use some JavaScript to achieve what you're trying.

You'll need to look at [keyboard events](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=javascript+keyboard+event&meta=#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=javascript+keyboard+event+site%3Astackoverflow.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=700fb4d1e2a0842b) to see which key is being pressed and then [focus](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=javascript+keyboard+event&meta=#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=javascript+focus+site%3Astackoverflow.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=700fb4d1e2a0842b) the correct element.

Answer (score 0):

```
        document.onkeyup = function keyPress(e) {
        wkey = e.which ? e.which : window.event.keyCode;
        var ch = String.fromCharCode(wkey).trim();
        var chlower = ch.toLowerCase().trim();

        var foo = [];
        var fo = [];
        var k = 0;
        var lastword;
        var looping = [];
        var lastwordforkeypress;

        $('#ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_channelTreeView table').each(function(l, table) {
            looping[l] = $(table).text().trim();
            if (looping[l].indexOf(ch) === 0 || looping[l].indexOf(chlower) === 0) {
                lastwordforkeypress = looping[l];
            }
        });

        $('#ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_channelTreeView table').each(function(i, table) {
            foo[i] = $(table).text().trim();
            if (foo[i].indexOf(ch) === 0 || foo[i].indexOf(chlower) === 0) {
                fo = $('#keystroke').html().split(',');

                if (fo[k].trim() == foo[i].trim()) {                        
                    k = k + 1;
                }
                else {
                    $('#keystroke').html($('#keystroke').html() + foo[i] + ',');
                    lastword = foo[i].trim();
                    var keystroke = $('#keystroke').html()
                    if (keystroke.indexOf(ch) === 0 || keystroke.indexOf(chlower) === 0) {
                        $('table').select().css({ backgroundColor: 'white' });
                        $(table).select().css({ backgroundColor: 'orange' });
                        if (lastwordforkeypress == lastword) {
                            $('#keystroke').html('');
                            k = 0;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#keystroke').html('');
                        k = 0;
                        $('#keystroke').html($('#keystroke').html() + foo[i] + ',');
                        $('table').select().css({ backgroundColor: 'white' });
                        $(table).select().css({ backgroundColor: 'orange' });
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I achieved through Jquery. But the thing is i couldn't scroll the panel scroll bar when focus is going down on tree view. have no idea at all. help needed.